# java application reads data from card reader

Tags: java, device, device-driver, smartcard, javacard

If someone wants to write a java application that interacts with a physical device, specifically a reader (e.g. as when you go in a hotel, gym, bank etc and you pass the card through a reader and the application finds you in the database) how is this done?
Is there a java api to interact with the reader and get the cards data?
When a company creates a reader (physical device) does it provide relevant apis?
Are the physical details abstracted from the application programmer?
I need to interact with a reader in java but I do not know how to start.
Any input is highly welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can start playing with the [javax.smartcardio](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html) package.

It's an official Oracle product to allow smart card interaction. This doesn't solve the **general** problem of device communication (in Unix, simply open `/dev/whatever0` with right permissions as it was a file), but may help you with your smart card scenario.

Comment: Can I request that instead of providing a link that simply says 'this' that you use a more descriptive term?  That makes it easier for people who are scanning through the answers.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.So the reader device is irrelevant?I just need to know if the smart card is compliant to ISO/IEC 7816-4 APDUs?Or am I mixing the concepts here?

Comment: I believe that **all** smart card readers are compliant to that standard. I'm no big expert in that, I would try with a "hello world"-level application first. As you can see, there is sample code.

Comment: It will depend entirely on the card reader.  Some use serial ports, other use USB; some need specific drivers and some appear just as HID input devices (so they act like a keyboard).  Also, the smartcardio package is really designed for smart cards with an embedded chip, rather than simple magnetic stripe cards.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the platform. For instance ORACLE states [Java Communications 3.0 API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) to work with:

> The Java Communications API (also known as javax.comm) provides applications access to RS-232 hardware (serial ports) and limited access to IEEE-1284 (parallel ports), SPP mode.

This could give you a starter.

Comment: Also, if you need to use serial ports, SerialIO.com sell a very good cross-platform serial port API.

Comment: In which case would I need to access via serial ports?If the communications api can not be used?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have generic usb drivers for smartcard readers, as well as a daemon that can detect when new readers are plugged in, and some diagnostics information when the readers initiate a connection with a smartcard (either through contact, or contactless/NFC).
http://www.linuxnet.com/

jpcsc can then be used as a java API towards the card, so you can read and write. You are abstracted away from the reader hardware, but you still need to know a lot about the specifics of the smartcard - which version of Javacard/GlobalPlatform it uses, what the crypto keys are that are used if you want to establish a secure connection, etc.

Or you can buy a complete development environment including a card, a reader, and an IDE (usually based on Eclipse) from a smartcard manufacturer such as G & D, Oberthur, Gemalto...

Comment: jpcsc ist quit old and the development stoped long ago. You should ise javax.smartcardio in future projects, because there is now future with jpcsc.